# Bash Getting variables from a file safely

Tags: bash, parsing, variable-assignment

I have a script that stores variables inside a .txt file for later use. I want to retrieve those variables from the file safely.

How I have it setup now:

Settings.txt

```
var1=value1
var2=value2
...
```

Script

```
for i in $(cat Settings.txt); do $i done
# So now "var1" has the value "value1", and so on
```

This works, but is dangerous, as someone could inject code trough that txt file.

I know about the `source` command, but that too has the same problem. So, how to achieve the same functionality safely?

Comment: What do you mean by `safely`? Stop any code from execution?

Comment: @sobolevn Yeah, I don't want that any code would accidently be exeuted from the txt file. If the file would have the line `rm -fr /` it would do some unwanted damage :/

Comment: @BonBon : Do the variables always start with `var`?

Comment: @sjsam No, thay can be any variable name with upper- and lowercase characters and a '_'. The value will either be 1, 0 or some short string without special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want separate steps for validation and variable creation:

**Update, based on `declare`**: A simpler approach that is still safe is to use the `declare` builtin to define the variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read the file line by line.
while read -r line; do
  declare -- "$line"
done <<'EOF'
  var1=value1
  var2=value2
EOF
```

- The `declare` command fails with input lines that aren't valid shell variable assignments, but it fails *safely* in that the line is never evaluated as a *command*.
- Note that the values are read as *literals*, exactly as defined in the file (except for removal of trailing whitespace).
- If you also want to support single- or double-quoted values, use the following `declare` command instead:
  `declare -- "$(xargs -I {} printf %s {} <<<"$line")"`
  but note that using *embedded, escaped* quotes of the same type in values is *not* supported (this is a limitation of `xargs`).

---

**Original answer, based on `printf -v`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read the file line by line.
while read -r line; do
  # Split the line into name and value using regex matching.
  if [[ $line =~ ^([^=]+)=(.*)$ ]]; then
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} now contains the variable name, 
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} the value.
    # Use printf -v to store the value in a variable.
    printf -v "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" %s "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  fi
done <<'EOF'
  var1=value1
  var2=value2
EOF

# Print the variables that were created (based on name prefix `var`).
for name in ${!var*}; do
  printf '%s=%s\n' "$name" "${!name}"
done
```

- Note that the values are read as *literals*, exactly as defined in the file (except for removal of trailing whitespace).

  - If there are values that are single- or double-quoted and you want to remove the quotes, use the following `printf -v` command instead:
    `printf -v "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" %s "$(xargs -I {} printf %s {} <<<"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")"`
    but note that quoted strings with *embedded, escaped* quotes of the same type are *not* supported.
- Should be safe to use, because `printf -v` is used to create the variables - the shell doesn't directly source the assignment statements, which is where injection could happen.
- Lines not recognized as variable assignments are simply skipped.
- Regex `^([^=]+)=(.*)$` matches any line that starts with (`^`) a least 1 (`+`) character other than `=` (`[^=]`), followed directly by `=`, followed by any remaining sequence of characters (`.*`) through the end of the line (`$`). The parentheses around `([^=]+)` and `(.*)` ensure that the captured substrings are saved in special Bash array variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`, starting at index 1.

  - For simplicity, no attempt is made to validate the variable name up front, which means that the `printf -v` command may fail later.

Comment: @BonBon: Glad to hear it; it just occurred to me that using `declare` rather than `printf -v` allows for a simpler solution; please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can check variables assignments format before sourcing :

```
#!/bin/bash

file=Settings.txt
regex_varname='^[a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\'
regex_varvalue='[a-zA-Z0-9]\+$'

is_safe_var() {
  while read var; do
    grep -q $regex_varname=$regex_varvalue <<< "$var" || return 1
  done < "$file"
}

is_safe_var && source "$file" || echo "Break"
```

The variables `$regex_varname` and `$regex_varvalue` are assigned patterns for variables authorized name and value :

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]` : variable name beginning with one or more alphanumeric character or `_`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]\+$` : variable value ending with one or more alphanumeric character

The loop in function `is_safe_var` checks for each line of `Settings.txt` if variables assignments match the pattern `$regex_varname=$regex_varvalue`.

If one line fails the test, it returns from function with error code and `echo "Break"`, otherwise `Settings.txt` is sourced.

**Note :** you may complete the character range `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`  and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with authorized characters in your variables names and values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please add some explanations what your regex does, as it's kinda hard to follow.